# How do I extract columns names from rows and promote them to headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I`m reading a csv and the data is a little bit messy. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
ocorrencias = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding="1252", header=None)
ocorrencias = ocorrencias.drop([0, 1, 2, 4, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], axis=1)
```

Output:

[image: output]

And I want to remove columns names from rows and promote them to the headers, so the dataframe will be like::

[image: after]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: This is impossible to replicate without a proper example. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a good  pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful

Comment: names could be simpler to set manually `df.columns = [f'ColumName{number}' for number in range(len(df.columns))]` and later you can slice values on `:` to remove first part - `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(': ').str[1])`

Comment: do you really want headers `ColumnName` or it is only example and in real data it may have different name?

Comment: @furas That`s right, it`s only an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split(': ')` to keep only part after `:`  in cells

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(': ', 1).str[1])
```

You can use also `split(': ')` to get column names from any row (ie. from first row `.iloc[0]`)

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0].str.split(': ', 1).str[0]
```

---

Minimal working code

First it has to get headers before names are removed from cells.

I used `random` to generate random value - but using `random.seed(0)` you should get the same values as in my result.

I use `1` in `split(': ', 1)` to split it only on first `:`  because sometimes there  can be more `:`  if you would have text values.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)  #  to get the same random values in every test

df = pd.DataFrame([f'{col}: {random.randint(0,100)}' 
                    for col in ['hello', 'world', 'of', 'python']]
                    for row in range(3))

print(df)

df.columns = df.iloc[0].str.split(': ', 1).str[0]
print(df)

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(': ', 1).str[1])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
            0          1       2           3
0   hello: 49  world: 97  of: 53   python: 5
1   hello: 33  world: 65  of: 62  python: 51
2  hello: 100  world: 38  of: 61  python: 45

0       hello      world      of      python
0   hello: 49  world: 97  of: 53   python: 5
1   hello: 33  world: 65  of: 62  python: 51
2  hello: 100  world: 38  of: 61  python: 45

0 hello world  of python
0    49    97  53      5
1    33    65  62     51
2   100    38  61     45
```

Comment: so you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.

Comment: It says I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote (I`ll try later), but I've marked your answer as accepted. Thank you again!